# How can I prevent bash from reporting an error when attempting to call a non-existing script?

Tags: bash, unix

I am writing a simple script in bash to check whether or not a bunch of dependencies are installed on the current system. My script attempts to run a sample script with the `-h` flag, greps the output for a keyword i would expected to be returned by the sample scripts, and therefore knows whether or not the sample script is installed on the system.

I then pass this through a conditional statement that basically says `sample scripts = OK` or `sample scripts = FAIL`. However, in the case in which the sample script isn't installed on the system, bash throws the warning `-bash: sample_script: command not found`. How can I prevent this from displaying? I tried using the 1>&2 error redirection, but the warning still appears on the screen (I want the `OK/FAIL` output text to be displayed on the user's screen upon running my script).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `command -h 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to suppress errors (stderr) and let the "OK" or "FAIL" you are echoing (stdout) pass through, you would do:

```
./yourscript.sh 2> /dev/null
```

Although the better approach would be to test whether sample_script is executable before trying to execute it. For instance:

```
if [ -x "$script" ]; then
   *do whatever generates FAIL or OK*
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

@devnull dixit

```
command -h 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to be independent of `which`, `whence`, `type -p` and whatnot:

```
pathto () {
  DIRLIST=$(echo "$PATH"|tr : ' ')
  for e in "$@"; do
    for d in $DIRLIST; do
      test -f "$d/$e" -a -x "$d/$e" && echo "$d/$e"
    done
  done
}
```

`pathto script` will echo the full path if it can be found (and is executable). Returning 0 or 1 instead left as an exercise :-)

Comment: Are you staying away from `which`, ... in an effort not to rely on non-POSIX extensions? Your function could be simplified to `pathto () { local IFS=:; for e; do for d in $PATH; do test -x "$d/$e" && echo "$d/$e"; done done }`

Comment: Yes, the idea is to make only a minimum of assumption about what Bourne-type shell runs this. This means `local` can't be used.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So with a POSIX-only shell in mind, we get `pathto() { (IFS=:; for e; do for d in $PATH; do test -x "$d/$e" && echo "$d/$e" && break; done done) }` (using a subshell). To also report exit codes properly: `pathto() { (IFS=: ec=0; for e do lec=1; for d in $PATH; do test -x "$d/$e" && lec=0 && echo "$d/$e" && break; done; test "$lec" = '1' && ec=1; done; test $# -gt 0 -a $ec -eq 0) }
` (failure to find at least one argument results in exit code 1).

Answer (score 0):

for bash:

```
if ! type -P sample_script &> /dev/null; then
    echo Error: sample_script is not installed. Come back later. >&2
    exit 1
fi
sample_script "$@"
```

Comment: Not that it hurts, but isn't the `&> /dev/null` redundant, given that `type -P` outputs nothing if no match is found?